# Context variables not being passed to template in Django class-based view

Tags: python, django, date, web-applications

Banging my head against a wall.. I'm trying to return a table of Job objects, with views separated by month. I'm passing 'year' and 'month' variables through get_context_data, yet in my template they're returning blank strings. Even ChatGPT can't find anything wrong lol. Can anyone spot something?

Here's my view:

```
class pipelineMonthView(SingleTableMixin, MonthMixin, ListView):
    model = Job
    table_class = JobTable
    form_class = JobForm
    bulk_actions = PipelineBulkActionsForm
    template_name = "main_app/pipeline_by_month.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['job_form'] = self.form_class
        context['bulk_actions'] = self.bulk_actions
        context['year'] = 2023 #will be date.today().year
        context['month'] = 2 #will be date.today().month
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        print(f'the result of self.get_month: {self.get_month()}')
        queryset = queryset.filter(job_date=self.get_month())
        return queryset
```

My URL, including URLs from main_app:

```
    path('pipeline/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.pipelineMonthView.as_view(model=Job), name="pipeline-by-month"),
```

And my URL tag: `{% url 'main_app:pipeline-by-month' year month %}`

My template is at `static/main_app/pipeline_by_month.html`.

Here's the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 449, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 698, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /main_app/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'pipeline-by-month' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['main_app/pipeline/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

Edit to add some more info:
My Job model is below. The 'job_date' attribute is calculated from 'year' and 'month' attributes, as the day of the month is not relevant in my app.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, editable=True, default=date.today().year)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=2, editable=True, default=date.today().month)
    job_date = models.DateField(editable=False, null=True, default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.job_date = f'{self.year}-{int(self.month):02d}-01'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Adding the html where I'm using the code. It's in the navbar of my base.html file, so I'm just including that block.

```
    {% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark p-0" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">
        <img src="{% static 'main_app/images/bwcat_logo_720x720.png' %}" alt="Bootstrap" width="65" height="65">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main_app:pipeline' %}">Pipeline</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main_app:pipeline-by-month' year month %}">Pipeline Monthly</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Clients
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'main_app:client-add' %}">Add Client</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'main_app:client-list' %}">View Clients</a></li>
          </ul>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Vendors
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'main_app:invoice-request-page' %}">Request Invoices</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'main_app:vendor-add' %}">Add Vendor</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'main_app:vendor-list' %}">View Vendors</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Placeholder</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you use `url` in `pipeline_by_month.html`?

Comment: Yes I do. Updated with some more information.

Comment: Can you display the context dict in your template ?

Comment: show your HTML code. Where is the get_month function you called in get_queryset ?

Comment: @Corralien, yeah, I seem to be able to call month and year in the html template no problem.

Comment: @LucasGrugru I added the html template, but get_month() is one of the methods included with the MonthMixin.

Comment: Your error says `NoReverseMatch at /main_app/` does the view for _that_ url add `year` and `month` to the content?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, thank you for your comment! This helped me realized I was misunderstanding how context worked, that the context needs to be available in every view where the _URL that needs the context_ will be accessible. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a block which will be reused multiple times. Hence the context variable `month` and `year` won't be availbe in all the views. In this case, you need to use [custom `context processor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) which are available in all pages. You can write one like this:

```
#yourapp/custom_context_processor.py

def get_year_month(request):
    # you put your custom logic here
    year = request.GET.get('year', 2023)
    month= request.GET.get('month', 2)
    return {
       'year': year,
       'month': month
    }
```

Then add it to `TEMPLATES` in your `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
 {
   'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
   'APP_DIRS': True,
   'OPTIONS': {
      'context_processors': [
      'django.template.context_processors.debug',
      'django.template.context_processors.request',
      'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
      'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      'your_app.custom_context_processor.get_year_month' #<-- here
   ],
  },
 },
]
```

### Update

More simplified implementation can be like this using [`NOW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#now):

```
{% now "Y" as current_year %}
{% now "M" as current_month %}

{% url 'main_app:pipeline-by-month' current_year current_month %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the indentation was wrong in the post but correct in my code. I fixed it above.

Comment: Thank you! I should have mentioned in the post, but my 'logic' for the year and month is going to just be a simple `date.today().year` and `date.today().month`, so they won't need any extra context from any views. The page would load the Job objects from the current month, and then have navigation links/dropdowns to select other months to view. I feel like this implementation should be simple and doable all from the view. I wonder if there's somewhere else I could look?

Comment: Thank you! I was just able to get your original custom context processor to work. I'll check out the simplified solution in the morning. I was misunderstanding the logic behind getting context, and upon a careful rethink it finally clicked that 'year' and 'month' need to be available in EACH of the views where the URL will be accessible, _not_ the view that the URL leads to. Thanks again for your help!